# Add "Additional Column Settings" to Site Collumn with Visual Studio for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, site-column

Can I restrict a Site-Collumn with the common "Additional Column Settings" which we see in the Browser when I create the Collumn in a Feature in Microsoft Visual Studio? (I would like to create a Single Line of Text Site Collumn with the restriction to just 30 chars)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
  <Field
       ID="{8ed076c2-64cf-4dbf-9f63-002cb5a28567}"
       Name="My Headline"
       DisplayName="My Headline"
       Type="Text"
       Required="FALSE"
       Group="Custom Site Columns">
  </Field>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this attribute in Field node

```
MaxLength="30"
```

Comment: ok, thank you, I tried to search for a List of all Attributes availabele for those Site Columns. Could you find such one? pls

Comment: Please refer to the following link for details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979575(v=office.15).aspx